# how to use multiple scenario in single controller in yii2?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, yii2

Hi all how to use multiple scenario in single controller action in yii2.i have one dropdown onchange depend on onchange form field will change.so i used scenario but controller accept only one scenario.is it possible to use multiple scenario in a single action.please help..

```js
Model:

 public function rules()
    {
        return [
            //[['discount_type', 'discount_name', 'discount_percentage', 'discount_from_quantity','discount_to_quantity' ,'discount_start_date', 'discount_end_date', 'discount_status', 'access_code', 'code_discount', 'no_of_tickets', 'status','ticket_name'], 'required'],
            [['discount_type','ticket_name'],'required'],
            [['event_id', 'ticket_id', 'discount_from_quantity','discount_to_quantity', 'no_of_tickets', 'status'], 'integer'],
            [['discount_type', 'discount_status','ticket_name'], 'string'],
            [['discount_start_date', 'discount_end_date', 'timestamp'], 'safe'],
            [['discount_name'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
            [['discount_percentage', 'code_discount','access_code'], 'string', 'max' => 100,],
            [['discount_start_date', 'discount_end_date','access_code','no_of_tickets'],'required','on' => 'access'],
            [['discount_start_date', 'discount_end_date','code_discount','no_of_tickets','discount_percentage'],'required','on' => 'code'],
            [['discount_name','discount_percentage','discount_start_date', 'discount_end_date','no_of_tickets','discount_from_quantity','discount_to_quantity'],'required','on' => 'group'],
            ];
           
    }
```

```css
Controller:

public function actionCreate($id)
    {
  //echo $id;
        $model_discount= new EventticketDiscount();
       $model_discount->scenario = 'code';
        $model_ticketid = new EventTicket_ex();
        
        $ticketid=$model_ticketid->find()->where(['event_id'=>$id])->one();
        
        $ticketname=ArrayHelper::map($model_ticketid->find()->where(['event_id'=>$id])->all(),'ticket_id','ticket_name'); 
        
   
        if ($model_discount->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
   
   $model_discount->attributes=$_POST['EventticketDiscount'];

         if(isset($_POST['EventticketDiscount']['ticket_name']) && $_POST['EventticketDiscount']['ticket_name']!==array())
            $model_discount->ticket_name=implode(',',$_POST['EventticketDiscount']['ticket_name']);
            
           
      $model_discount->event_id = $id;
      $model_discount->ticket_id = $ticketid->ticket_id;
   $model_discount->save();

    
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model_discount->discount_id]);
        } else {
            return $this->renderAjax('create', [
                'model_discount' => $model_discount,'ticketname'=>$ticketname,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

```html
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
     <?= $form->field($model_discount, 'discount_type')
                ->dropDownList(ZHtml::enumItem($model_discount, 'discount_type'),['prompt'=>'Select Type','onchange'=>'js:discountShow(this.value)'])
                ->label(FALSE)
                ?> 
           
    <?= $form->field($model_discount, 'event_id')->hiddenInput(['value'=>""])->label(false); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model_discount, 'ticket_id')->hiddenInput(['value'=>""])->label(false); ?>
    
    
    <div id="discountname" style="display:none">
  

    <?= $form->field($model_discount, 'discount_name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
    </div>

    <div id="discountpercentage" style="display:none">
    <?= $form->field($model_discount, 'discount_percentage')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
    </div>
    
    <div id="discountdate" style="display:none">

    <?= $form->field($model_discount, 'discount_start_date')->textInput() ?>

    <?= $form->field($model_discount, 'discount_end_date')->textInput() ?>
    </div>


    <div id="accesscode" style="display:none">
    <?= $form->field($model_discount, 'access_code')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
    </div>
    
     <div id="discountcode" style="display:none">

    <?= $form->field($model_discount, 'code_discount')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
    </div>

   <div id="discountcount" style="display:none">
    <?= $form->field($model_discount, 'no_of_tickets')->textInput() ?>
   </div>
   
    <div id="discountquantity" style="display:none">
    <?= $form->field($model_discount, 'discount_from_quantity')->textInput() ?>
    
    <?= $form->field($model_discount, 'discount_to_quantity')->textInput() ?>
    </div>
    
    <div id="ticketname" style="display:none">
    <?= $form ->field($model_discount, 'ticket_name[]')
           ->checkboxList($ticketname)->label('Select Tickets');?>
    </div>
    
   
   <div id="discountstatus" style="display:none">
    <!-- $form->field($model_discount, 'discount_status')->dropDownList(ZHtml::enumItem($model_discount, 'discount_status'),['prompt' => 'Select Status'])-->

    <?= $form->field($model_discount, 'status')->hiddenInput(['value'=>1])->label(false); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model_discount, 'timestamp')->hiddenInput()->label(false);?>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton($model_discount->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model_discount->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>
    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

    </div>

    

<script>
 function discountShow(type)
 {
  alert(type);  
 
  
  if(type=="Group Discount"){
           document.getElementById('discountname').style.display="block";
           document.getElementById('ticketname').style.display="block";
                 document.getElementById('discountpercentage').style.display="block";
                 document.getElementById('discountdate').style.display="block";
                 document.getElementById('discountcount').style.display="block";
                 document.getElementById('discountquantity').style.display="block";
                 document.getElementById('discountstatus').style.display="block";
                 document.getElementById('accesscode').style.display="none";
                 document.getElementById('discountcode').style.display="none";
                
               
   }
                else if(type=="Access Code Discount"){
     
     document.getElementById('discountname').style.display="none";
                 document.getElementById('discountpercentage').style.display="none"; 
                 document.getElementById('discountquantity').style.display="none";
                 document.getElementById('discountcode').style.display="none";
                 document.getElementById('discountdate').style.display="block";
                 document.getElementById('accesscode').style.display="block";
                 document.getElementById('discountcount').style.display="block";
                 document.getElementById('discountstatus').style.display="block";
                 document.getElementById('ticketname').style.display="block";
                 //return false;
    }
  
             else if(type=="Code Discount"){
     document.getElementById('discountpercentage').style.display="block";
                 document.getElementById('discountdate').style.display="block";
                 document.getElementById('discountcode').style.display="block";
                 document.getElementById('discountcount').style.display="block";
                 document.getElementById('discountstatus').style.display="block";
                 document.getElementById('discountname').style.display="none";
                  document.getElementById('accesscode').style.display="none";
                  document.getElementById('discountquantity').style.display="none";
                  document.getElementById('ticketname').style.display="block";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the scenario option in the options of the activeform. and you can change it with jquery if you want. Also add an id for the form so the client side validation works too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```
[['username', 'email', 'password'], 'required', 'on' => [self::SCENARIO_REGISTER, self::SCENARIO_OTHER]]
```